# Is the scylladb build hardcoded to work only with gnu gcc?

Tags: build, freebsd, clang++, scylla

The python configure.py contains a line

```
gcc_linker_output = subprocess.check_output(['gcc', '-###', '/dev/null', '-o', 't'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('utf-8')
```

The comments before this line indicate scylladb uses a custom dynamic linker and references details about the ABI layout.

Is there code missing from the configure.py script which would enable building on a strict llvm environment, or is that not possible at this time?

I am building Scylladb on FreeBSD 13 which uses clang++ 13.0.0.
I am on branch master, commit 0efdc45d5981868b1b6, Setp 8, 2022.
I patched SCYLLA-VERSION-GEN to get past the date --utf and USAGE issues, and patched config.py with an entry to read ID from freebsd for the boost error message.
I run configure.py with

```
./configure.py --mode=release --compiler=clang++ --cflags=-I/usr/local/include
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact ScyllaDB builds with clang. However its dependency Seastar is very dependent on Linux. If you want it to run on FreeBSD you'll have to port Seastar first (see reactor_backend.{cc,hh})